# Nested query and grouping by unions (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help writing a query to get some information but I am having trouble writing it.

```
[table_People]
int id
var name

[table_Tools]
int id
var name

[table_Activity1]
int person_id
int tool_id
date delivery_date

[table_Activity2]
int person_id
int tool_id
date installation_date
```

The query needs to return a list of all people and the name of the most recent tool they used in either activity 1 or 2 (the most recent activity that happened between the two).

```
SELECT
    people.id   AS personId,
    people.name AS personName,
    (
        SELECT
            tools.name AS toolName
        FROM
            activity1
        JOIN
            tools ON tools.id=activity1.tool_id
        WHERE
            activity1.id=people.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            tools.name AS toolName
        FROM
            activity2
        JOIN
            tools ON tools.id=activity2.tool_id
        WHERE
            activity2.id=people.id
        ORDER BY
            installationDate,deliveryDate
    ) AS toolName
FROM
    people
ORDER BY
    people.name
ASC
```

The problem I am having is that I can't sort by date (delivery or installation) as I get errors because they are different column names.

Comment: the provided query shouldn't work since the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: What are the Primary Keys of `Activity1` and `Activity2`?

Answer (score 4):

Using UNION in a subquery creates a derived temporary table. Columns that aren't selected are not in the result set, so you can't ORDER on a column that's not in the SELECT clause.

When using UNION, the first column name that is used in the SELECT clause is used in the result set (similar to an alias, though you could also use an alias).

Just be sure to name the column in the SELECT clause.

You also need a LIMIT clause to restrict the subquery to a single row:

```
SELECT
    people.id   AS personId,
    people.name AS personName,
    (
        SELECT
            tools.name AS toolName, delivery_date
        FROM
            activity1
        JOIN
            tools ON tools.id=activity1.tool_id
        WHERE
            activity1.id=people.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            tools.name AS toolName, installation_date
        FROM
            activity2
        JOIN
            tools ON tools.id=activity2.tool_id
        WHERE
            activity2.id=people.id
        ORDER BY
            deliveryDate
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS toolName
FROM
    people
ORDER BY
    people.name
ASC
```

Here's a more simple example to illustrate the issue:

```
SELECT fish FROM sea
UNION
SELECT dog FROM land
ORDER BY fish
```

Is the same as:

```
SELECT fish AS animal FROM sea
UNION
SELECT dog AS animal FROM land
ORDER BY animal
```

The results are put into a derived temporary table, and you can name the columns whatever you want, but the first name that you use sticks.

Answer (score 2):

My solution puts the unions together in a subquery and then orders by them.  You only want the first row, so you need a limit clause (or rownum = 1 in Oracle or top 1 in MSSQL):

```
SELECT people.id   AS personId,
       people.name AS personName, 
       (SELECT toolname
        FROM ((SELECT tools.name AS toolName, delivery_date as thedate
               FROM activity1 a
               WHERE a.PersonId = people.id
              ) union all
              (SELECT tools.name AS toolName, installation_date as thedate
               FROM activity2 a
               WHERE a.PersonId = people.id
              )
             ) a join
             tools t
             on a.toolsid = t.toolsid
        order by 2 desc
        limit 1
       ) AS toolName
FROM people
ORDER BY people.name ASC
```

To simplify the query, I also removed the innermost join to tools.

Comment: +1, this is the best solution I find here, cool out of the box thinking

Answer (score 0):

you cannot sort columns without specifying them after your `select`.

For Example:

```
select name from people order by name

select a1.delivery_date, t.name from activity1 a1, tools t 
order by a1.delivery_date,t.name
```

All selected columns for the projection MUST be defined in the `order by` definition as well. In your example both select statements are just taking `tools.name as toolname` but you want to sort by other columns.

Comment: I cant "select a1.delivery_date, t.name" because it is nested in a bigger select projected as "(select a1.delivery_date, t.name...) AS toolName. I cannot select 2 things and then only ask for a toolName.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
SELECT
    people.id   AS personId,
    people.name AS personName,
    IF (
        (SELECT
            deliveryDate AS dDate
        FROM
            activity1
        WHERE
            person_id=personId) --assuming you have only one row returned here, else limit by some condition
        >
        (SELECT
            installationDate AS iDate
         FROM
            activity2
         WHERE
            person_id=personId) --assuming you have only one row returned here, else limit by some condition
         , (SELECT
                tools.name AS toolName
            FROM
                activity1
            JOIN
                tools ON tools.id=activity1.tool_id
            WHERE
                activity1.person_id=personId)
         , (SELECT
                tools.name AS toolName
            FROM
                activity2
            JOIN
                tools ON tools.id=activity2.tool_id
            WHERE
                activity2.person_id=personId)
           ) AS toolName
FROM
    people        
ORDER BY
    people.name
ASC
```

This query assumes there is only record per person in activity tables. If there are more you need to limit your select result set based on sum maximum condition or so which only u know.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL version (possibly you can get more compact code from it):

```
Select * from 
(
  Select toolName, person_id, Max(TargetDate) as MaxDate
  From
        (
            SELECT tools.name AS toolName, activity1.person_id, activity1.delivery_date as targetDate
            FROM
                activity1
            JOIN
                tools ON tools.id=activity1.tool_id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                tools.name AS toolName, activity2.person_id, activity2.installation_date as TargetDate
            FROM
                activity2
            JOIN
                tools ON tools.id=activity2.tool_id
        )
 Group by toolName, person_id

) preselect
    join
    (
    Select toolName, person_id, Max(TargetDate)
    From
            (
                SELECT tools.name AS toolName, activity1.person_id, activity1.delivery_date as targetDate
                FROM
                    activity1
                JOIN
                    tools ON tools.id=activity1.tool_id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    tools.name AS toolName, activity2.person_id, activity2.installation_date as TargetDate
                FROM
                    activity2
                JOIN
                    tools ON tools.id=activity2.tool_id
            )) result on result.toolName = preselect.toolName and result.person_id = preselect.person_id and result.TargetDate = preselect.MaxDate
```

Comment: Using MySQL as tagged in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.id             AS person_id
  , p.name           AS person_name
  , CASE WHEN COALESCE(a1.delivery_date, '1000-01-01')
              > COALESCE(a2.installation_date, '1000-01-01')
           THEN t1.name
           ELSE t2.name
    END              AS tool_name
FROM 
    People AS p
  LEFT JOIN 
    Activity1 AS a1
        ON (a1.tool_id, a1.delivery_date) =
           ( SELECT tool_id, delivery_date
             FROM Activity1 AS a
             WHERE a.person_id = p.id
             ORDER BY delivery_date DESC
             LIMIT 1
           )
  LEFT JOIN 
    Tools AS t1
        ON t1.id = a1.tool_id
  LEFT JOIN 
    Activity2 AS a2
        ON (a2.tool_id, a2.installation_date) =
           ( SELECT tool_id, installation_date
             FROM Activity2 AS a
             WHERE a.person_id = p.id
             ORDER BY installation_date DESC
             LIMIT 1
           )
  LEFT JOIN 
    Tools AS t2
        ON t2.id = a2.tool_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select people.id as person_id,people.name as person_name,tools.name as toolsname
from table_people people left join 
(
select
      case when installation_date>delivery_date then act2.tool_id 
                 else act1.tool_id end as recent_most_tool_id,
      case when installation_date>delivery_date then act2.person_id
                 else act1.person_id end as recent_most_person_id
    from table_activity1 act1 inner join table_activity2    act2
         on act1.person_id=act2.person_id)X
on people.id=X.recent_most_person_id
inner join table_tools tools
on tools.id=X.recent_most_tool_id